# How to make div height fixed from any situation

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Here is the code. I'm using bootstrap.

I want to make div height fixed from any situation what come from database.

If book title and description have more character then don't increase height and if character less then don't effect of div height.

How can I solve this?

```
            <?php 
              echo "<div class='item active'>";
              echo "<div class='row'>";
                foreach($books as $key=>$value)
                {

                    //if we can divide $key by six without remainder

                    if ($key % 6 ==0 AND $key!=0 ) 
                    {
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='item'>";
                        echo "<div class='row'>";
                    }
                   echo '<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumbnails">';
        echo ' <div class="fff"> ';
        echo ' <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="'. base_url().'assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>';
                echo ' <strong>'.substr($value->BookTitle,0,40).'</strong><br>';
                echo '    <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> '.$value->BookAuthorName.'</strong><br>';
        echo ' <span style=" font-size:13px;">'.substr($value->BookDetail,0,70).'';   
        echo ' </span><a class="" href="'.base_url().'Book/'.str_replace(' ','-',$value->BookTitle).'">» Read More</a>';
        echo ' </div>';
              echo '</div>';
               }
            echo "</div>";  
            echo "</div>";?>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the col height in pixels?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you. Also, please format your code to eliminate scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a below/similar css class to the text elements to restrict them to same height and **trim content using CSS**:

```
.truncate {
width: 95%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```